# Getting error in OpenCV-python only in visual studio code but not in idle

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

I have been getting erros for opencv read commands in visual studio code but it works fine in idle

this is code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
  
FILE_NAME = 'volleyball.jpg'
try:
    # Read image from disk.
    img = cv2.imread(FILE_NAME)
  
    # Canny edge detection.
    edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
  
    # Write image back to disk.
    cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', edges)
except IOError:
    print ('Error while reading files !!!')
```

Error:

```
OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:801: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
  File "D:\doc\codes\python\openvc\new.py", line 13, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', edges)
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEooc.png)

Comment: Your image 'img' is empty, does your code read volleybal.jpg correctly?

Comment: i dont think it does, it runs like it should with idle of python i dont know what is different with vscode.

Comment: @avinashnair Are you sure the image is in the same directory as the script?

Comment: @3nws [yes](https://imgur.com/Tcp2arm)

Comment: `edges is None` or an empty array. please debug your code and determine the values of your variables.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz edges is None

Comment: @avinash nair I  think it is not caused by code. Have you ever tried to use other pictures?

Answer (score 0):

@ avinash nair. It worked for me. Are you sure filename(**volleyball.jpg**) is right or it is not in currently folder?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
  
FILE_NAME = 'flower.jpg'
try:
    # Read image from disk.
    img = cv2.imread(FILE_NAME)
  
    # Canny edge detection.
    edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
  
    # Write image back to disk.
    cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', edges)
except IOError:
    print ('Error while reading files !!!')
```

Output:
[image]